# await inside await or how to get parent scope? Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a fucntion:

```
suspend fun getChats() {
    val chatList = mutableListOf<Chat>()
    getMyChats { chats ->
        chats.forEach {
            it.getDetail().await()
        }
    }.await()
}
```

But compiler show `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` for `await()` which inside of `forEach` loop. How can I avoid this problem or how can I pass parent scope for it?

**getMyChats() receives a callback

Comment: Does `getMyChats` is accept lambda of type `suspend (Chat)->SomeOtherType`, aka suspendable lambda?

Comment: No, it receives a callback

Comment: what is type of callback?

Comment: @NonNull OnSuccessListener<? super TResult> var1

Comment: is `getMyChats` itself a suspend function that calls the callback before returning?

Comment: No, getMyChats is not suspend

Answer (score 1):

According to you, the `getMyChats` doesn't support taking suspendable block (lambda).

So you can wrap it with a [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html).

```kotlin
suspend fun getMyChatsSuspend(): List<Chat> = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    getMyChats { cont.resume(it) }
}
```

Now use your function like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun getChats() {
    ...
    val chats = getMyChatsSuspend()
    val chatDetails = chats.map{ chat.getDetail() }
    val chatDetailsAwait = awaitAll( *chatDetails.toTypedArray() )
}
```

Obviously just chain the calls instead of creating multiple variables if you want

If you want everything to be done in single line you can do:

```kotlin
val resolvedDetails = getMyChatsSuspend().map{ chat.getDetail() }.let { awaitAll(*it.toTypedArray()) }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to isolate the `getMyChats` function like @Animesh Sahu said, but that last call to `await()` looks very suspicious so I'll rewrite it.
I'll also assume that `await` is not necessarily on a `Deferred<T>`.

```
suspend fun getChats() {
    val chatList = mutableListOf<Chat>()

    val result = CompletableDeferred<List<Chat>>()
    getMyChats { result.complete(it) }.await()
    val chats = result.await()
    chats.forEach {
        it.getDetail().await()
    }
}
```

If you provide the function signatures of the functions involved I might be able give you a nicer solution.
Although without looking at anything else, I can tell you that the `getMyChats` function needs a refactor.